# SQL Server 2016 HTML response is manipulating attribute of external image and appending ï»¿ BOM character

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2014

I am accessing SSRS report with Java proxy and Apache httpclient.

For SSRS 2014 the report is working fine.

I am facing the problem with SSRS 2016.

**1st problem:** SSRS 2016 the same report is appending some `ï»¿` character which causes an exception in the browser like **invalid token**.

The snapshot is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">ï»¿$(document).ready(function(){PostRenderActions()});</script>
```

**2nd porblem:** If I am trying to access some exteranl image through the HTTP link the image is showing up in 5px width and 5px height. It seems it gets manipulated while generating the HTML content.

The generated HTML code is below.

```
<img class="resize100Width resize100Height" ALT="Report image" TITLE="Report image" style=" width: 5px; height: 5px;" src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Caterpillar/CM20161123-15855-24790?$cc-g$" />
```

With SSRS 2014, there no issue.

But for the same report in SSRS 2016, we are getting this issue.

How do we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding ?noresize parameter?